# JSTL is ignoring conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets, jstl

--This question is now solved. I have forgotten to add the JSTL library--

I am having a web based application which uses [jquery-toastmessage-plugin](http://akquinet.github.io/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/). I am using JSTL to capture URL parameters and display them via toast messages. Below is my related code at `index.jsp`.

```
<!--show messages-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.toastmessage.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.toastmessage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  

<script type="text/javascript">

    function showSuccessToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast', "${resultMessage}");
    }
    function showStickySuccessToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text     : 'Success Dialog which is sticky',
            sticky   : true,
            position : 'top-right',
            type     : 'success',
            closeText: '',
            close    : function () {
                console.log("toast is closed ...");
            }
        });

    }
    function showNoticeToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', "Notice  Dialog which is fading away ...");
    }
    function showStickyNoticeToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
             text     : 'Your Trial is expired. Please apply for an paid account.',
             sticky   : true,
             position : 'top-right',
             type     : 'notice',
             closeText: '',
             close    : function () {console.log("toast is closed ...");}
        });
    }
    function showWarningToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showWarningToast', "Warning Dialog which is fading away ...");
    }
    function showStickyWarningToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text     : 'Warning Dialog which is sticky',
            sticky   : true,
            position : 'top-right',
            type     : 'warning',
            closeText: '',
            close    : function () {
                console.log("toast is closed ...");
            }
        });
    }
    function showErrorToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "${resultMessage}");
    }
    function showStickyErrorToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text     : 'Error Dialog which is sticky',
            sticky   : true,
            position : 'top-right',
            type     : 'error',
            closeText: '',
            close    : function () {
                console.log("toast is closed ...");
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<!--/show messages-->

<!--error message display-->
 <c:if test="${param.isTrial!=null}">


    <c:if test="${not param.isTrial}">
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
              showStickyNoticeToast();
               };
         </script>

     </c:if>

  </c:if>
```

Below is how I pass arguments from URL.

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?isTrial=true");
```

Now my issue is, it really doesn't matter whether the `isTrial` param is true or false, null or not, the toastmessage is always getting displayed. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: What does <c:out var = "${param.isTrial}"/> display when there is no param? I think <c:if test ="${empty param.isTrial}">.........</c:if> should work.

Comment: @ramp: The `nulll` check us here `<c:if test="${param.isTrial!=null}">`

Comment: @ramp: I tried your way too. No good yet.

Comment: @ramp: Issue solved, I have forgotten to add the JSTL library.,

Comment: Basic :). Good for you. Just a note - the difference between empty and != null is that empty checks for both null and empty "" String. If you have an url "index.jsp?isTrial", then empty returns true and != null returns false.